# Automatic redirection Controller

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, controllers, redirect

I am creating a controller extending `\Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount` but it automatically get redirected to `http://example.com/customer/account/login/` how can I stop that. 
basically all the controller under `Magento_customer/Controller/Account` are extended by `\Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount`

but some are redirecting same as mine,like

```
Magento_customer/Controller/Account/index.php
```

while some are not redirected, like

```
Magento_customer/Controller/Account/create.php
```

Controller code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

class ControllerName extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: @Piyush I haven't tried it yet planing to implement this by next week, accordingly accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below method is responsible for redirection of any customer action

> **File path**:-  /vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php

```
public function beforeDispatch(AbstractAction $subject, RequestInterface $request)
{
    $action = strtolower($request->getActionName());
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $this->allowedActions) . ')$/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->session->authenticate()) {
            $subject->getActionFlag()->set('', ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}
```

This method will redirect your action to `customer/account/login` if it is  not there in `$this->allowedActions` array.

To solve your problem you need to override this method and add an extra condition in if statement for proper redirection of your action.

**You can add condition for you controller like below**

```
public function beforeDispatch(AbstractAction $subject, RequestInterface $request)
{
    $router = strtolower($request->getFullActionName());
    $action = strtolower($request->getActionName());
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $this->allowedActions) . ')$/i';

    if ($router != 'yourRouter_controller_action' && !preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->session->authenticate()) {
            $subject->getActionFlag()->set('', ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I prevent my controller from redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

extend the `Magento/Customer/Controller/Plugin/Account` class in your module.

rewrite the constructor and pass an array[ containing your controller name ], as the 2nd argument of the parent constructor. (parent::__constru....)

In your `di.xml` file set a preference to use your plugin instead of the one in Customer.

See the file by file below, might make more sense than the above :)

> Controller :

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Something extends AbstractAccount
{

public function execute()
{
    echo "Test";
}
}
```

> Plugin :

```
    <?php
    namespace Foo\Bar\Plugin;

    class Account extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account
    {
        public function __construct(
                  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
                  array $allowedActions = []
     ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $customerSession,
            array_merge(
                $allowedActions,
                [
                    'something' => 'something'
                ]
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

> di.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account" type="Foo\Bar\Plugin\Account"/>
 </config>
```

Comment: Obviously, change the namespace to match your own...

Comment: just tested it.. works. And  I think it's the simplest way. I see the other answer but why mess with code if you don't need to ;) cheers

Comment: I too have thought of this solution but I didn't opted it because it will work for every `something` action regardless of module, the much simpler solution will be to change action name to any one  that already exist in the  allowed array.

Comment: Not sure any actions are pre-allowed, haven't checked. And in my opinion if another module wants to use this even better, no need to add a second action name. Security is not the issue here, it's extending the AbstractController without forcing the login. What you do with it.. that's up to the developer. I think it's a problem that does not exist. I say the option is there, use it! don't reinvent the wheel just cause you can. Plus, there are other security checks in on the account side that would prevent someone form accessing secure information trough this controller, check them out.. ;)

Comment: and Thx for the edits, btw! ;) cheers

Comment: Agree with you !! there are pre-allowed actions and you can check them by`print_r($allowedActions)`.

Comment: then I need to change something.. :)

Comment: Ok, that should do it... now it follows the same syntax as the ones set by magento and it merges the arrays so the original ones are not lost.